Merge K Sorted Lists - Maximum Recursive Depth Reached
I've been working on Leetcode problem #23: Merge K Sorted Lists:

You are given an array of k linked-lists lists, each linked-list is sorted in ascending order.
Merge all the linked-lists into one sorted linked-list and return it.

I encountered the following problem:
I understand that a viable solution is using a divide and conquer approach, so I tried to implement this using recursion (like how I imagine Merge Sort works), but I keep running into the maximum recursion depth error and can't figure out why. I tried stepping through the debugger as well and it all seems to work fine until the last step.
Here is my code:
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution:
    def mergeKLists(self, lists: List[Optional[ListNode]]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        if len(lists) == 1:
            return lists[0]
        elif len(lists) == 2:
            return self.merge2Lists(lists[0], lists[1])

        v1 = self.mergeKLists(lists[:len(lists)//2])
        v2 = self.mergeKLists(lists[len(lists)//2:])

        return self.merge2Lists(v1, v2)
    
    def merge2Lists(self, list1, list2):
        result = ListNode()
        cur = result
        
        while list1 and list2:
            if list1.val < list2.val:
                cur.next = ListNode(list1.val)
                list1 = list1.next
            else:
                cur.next = ListNode(list2.val)
                list2 = list2.next
            cur = cur.next
        
        while list1:
            cur.next = ListNode(list1.val)
            list1 = list1.next
            cur = cur.next
        
        while list2:
            cur.next = ListNode(list2.val)
            list2 = list2.next
            cur = cur.next
        
        return result.next

The following three test cases are run when clicking Run in the LeetCode interface. They are encoded in this JSON format:


[[1,4,5],[1,3,4],[2,6]]
[]
[[]]


I get this error message:

Runtime Error
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
  [Previous line repeated 997 more times]
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    v1 = self.mergeKLists(lists[:len(lists)//2])
Line 6 in mergeKLists (Solution.py)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


I know there are iterative solutions for this divide and conquer approach, but I wanted to try and get this recursive one to work.
Where is the mistake?

The problem is just with one specific case, where the input lists is empty. You have not dealt with that base case, so that you fall into an infinite recursion.
Just add that base case and you're fine:
        if not lists:
            return None

Unrelated remarks
The above fixes the problem. But maybe some other things you could consider:
You don't need to deal with the last base case in your code, as it will be dealt with properly in the recursive case; you can remove this:
        elif len(lists) == 2:
            return self.merge2Lists(lists[0], lists[1])

It is nice that you made a new linked list without mutating the original linked lists. This is good practice. Do note however, that it comes at the cost of a O() space complexity (here  is the total number of nodes). As an alternative, you could try to re-use the existing nodes and just wire them together into the result list, which admittedly mutates the original lists, but for this challenge that seems to be fine.


We should handle the case where lists is empty by checking if not lists: at the beginning of the mergeKLists() function and returning None.

        while list1:
            cur.next = ListNode(list1.val)
            list1 = list1.next
            cur = cur.next
        
        while list2:
            cur.next = ListNode(list2.val)
            list2 = list2.next
            cur = cur.next



The above code block is also unnecessary. We should simply ensure the remaining elements are appended in merge2Lists() using cur.next = list1 if list1 else list2 or cur.next = list1 or list2 after the main merging loop (also see the comment below).


class Solution:
    def mergeKLists(self, lists: List[Optional[ListNode]]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        lists = [lst for lst in lists if lst]
        
        if not lists:
            return
        
        if len(lists) == 1:
            return lists[0]
        
        if len(lists) == 2:
            return self.merge2Lists(lists[0], lists[1])
        
        v1 = self.mergeKLists(lists[:len(lists) // 2])
        v2 = self.mergeKLists(lists[len(lists) // 2:])

        return self.merge2Lists(v1, v2)

    def merge2Lists(self, list1, list2):
        result = ListNode()
        cur = result
        
        while list1 and list2:
            if list1.val < list2.val:
                cur.next = list1
                list1 = list1.next
            else:
                cur.next = list2
                list2 = list2.next
            cur = cur.next
        
        cur.next = list1 if list1 else list2
        return result.next



While it is not applicable in this case, a potential way to bypass maximum recursion depth errors is using sys.setrecursionlimit(10 ** 5). However, this is strongly discouraged as it can lead to memory issues.



You can also use PriorityQueue(), but that does not seem to be what you want. It is easier to implement however:

from queue import PriorityQueue

class Solution:
    def mergeKLists(self, lists):
        result = cur = ListNode()
        queue = PriorityQueue()
        for index, node in enumerate(lists):
            if node:
                queue.put((node.val, index, node))
        while queue.qsize() > 0:
            item = queue.get()
            cur.next, index = item[2], item[1]
            cur = cur.next
            if cur.next:
                queue.put((cur.next.val, index, cur.next))
        return result.next


That handling of the remaining elements has nothing to do with the problem the question Is about, does it? Better make that clear. Btw you could even do cur.next = list1 or list2.

@nocomment Correct. The problem was just a minor edge case. cur.next = list1 or list2 is also correct.
